# Get creation date of an uploading file from metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create a rails appliaction ,I uploaded files using carrierwave and i'm tring to get the creation date of the uploading files.Is there a method or something to do that?!

Comment: Unverified, but perhaps you can use the "modified date" of the file: i.e `@user.avatar.file.mtime`, where `User` model has `mount_uploader :avatar`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby's File class method `#birthtime`. Assuming the file is mounted on `User.avatar`, and the file version you want to check is `thumbnail`:

```
##user = User.find(id)
path = user.avatar.thumbnail.path
creation_time = File.birthtime(path)
```

Comment: When excuted this code,I got:
(NotImplemenredError: birthtime() function is unimplemented on this machine)

Comment: Oh what's your ruby version? It is available in v2.2 but might not be in earlier versions. In that case you can try `#mtime`, but it is the last modification time, not creation time.

Comment: It's not related with the ruby version but more with the OS. Linux systems, for example, won't implement this.